# ASP FormatDateTime - Remove "Weekday"

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm sure this is going to turn out to be an easy answer, but I'll be damned if I can find it anywhere. I have a simple ASP script that displays the asp page date last modified. The code here:

```
<%

Dim strFileName
Dim dtmLastModified
Dim dtmLastModifiedDate

strFileName = Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
strFileName = Replace(strFileName, "/", "\")
strFileName = Server.MapPath(strFileName)

Set objFileSystemObject = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFile = objFileSystemObject.GetFile(strFileName)
dtmLastModified = objFile.DateLastModified
Set objFile = Nothing

Set objFileSystemObject = Nothing

dtmLastModifiedDate = FormatDateTime(dtmLastModified, 1)

Response.Write("Last Updated: " & dtmLastModifiedDate)
%>
```

displays like this:

```
Last Updated: Friday, April 10, 2015
```

All we need to do is remove the `Friday,` but can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: What about `Response.Write("Last Updated: " & Replace(dtmLastModifiedDate, WeekDayName(WeekDay(dtmLastModified)) & ", ", "")` to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

According to this link on [`FormatDateTime`](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_formatdatetime.asp), there is no format for just outputting the Month, Day, Year in the format that you want. Here is a way that you can return the `Month Day, Year` in that format from a datetime:

```
dtmLastModifiedDate = MonthName(Month(dtmLastModified)) & " " & Day(dtmLastModified) & ", " & Year(dtmLastModified)
```

You will have to replace your `FormatDateTime` line with this line for it to work.

This information was found on the cheat sheet in [this link](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/22/date-formatting-in-vbscript). Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, it is most vital to the people I work for that it appear as "April 10, 2015". No more, no less. Also, Javascript is out of the question. We'd have to have a whole battle with IT before they'd ever let us add any JS.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a method on formatting it within VBScript.